# Is it possible to traverse only a subtree of the AST with RecursiveASTVisitor

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

I want to traverse a project with a huge AST with clang's `RecursiveASTVisitor`. When I specify that the whole AST should be traversed (as follows), it takes a lot of time:

```
void MyVisitor::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext& context)
{
  TraverseDecl(context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
}
```

For that reason I would like to use the AST matcher to narrow the AST down to the relevant parts of the code that I want to traverse. Let's say I want to traverse only certain function declarations, then I have something along the lines of:

```
void MyVisitor::HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext& context)
{
    auto decl = context.getTranslationUnitDecl();
    auto relevantNodes = match(findAll(functionDecl(/* any matcher */).bind("function")), *decl, context);
    for(auto &relevantNode : relevantNodes)
    {
      const clang::FunctionDecl *relevantFunctionDecl = relevantNode.getNodeAs<clang::FunctionDecl>("function");
      if(relevantFunctionDecl)
      {
        TraverseDecl(relevantFunctionDecl);
        //----------^ cannot pass const clang::FunctionDecl* to function accepting clang::Decl*
      }
    }
}
```

In my code, the `getNodeAs<>` method returns a const pointer, however `TraverseDecl` accepts non-const pointers, i.e. the compilation fails.

Is there a way to traverse only certain parts of the AST?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to visit a subtree.  Simply do as shown in your code snippet, except adding `const_cast` to allow the pointer obtained from the matcher to be passed to `RecursiveASTVisitor`.  There is no issue with C++ undefined behavior because all of the AST objects are originally created without the `const` qualifier.

In general, the Clang API is a bit inconsistent regarding constness.  Many APIs, such as the matchers, deal with `const` pointers because they themselves do not modify the AST.  But while that's also true of `RecursiveASTVisitor`, it is somewhat common to write transformers using that that *do* modify the AST, so its API does not use `const`.

See the Clang Discourse discussion [Is it safe to cast-away constness to use Clang static analysis?](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/is-it-safe-to-cast-away-constness-to-use-clang-static-analysis/46477) for a similar question and commentary from the Clang devs.

(As an aside, I would argue this stems in part from the fact that C++ does not have a notion of "const polymorphism", which if it existed might allow an API to optionally deal uniformly with `const` or non-`const` pointers at the client's request.  Since the language forces a choice to be made, API designers have to pick whichever is a better fit for common usage, and clients therefore have to insert `const_cast` at some boundaries.)